# MySQL with Mathematical calculations

Tags: mysql, database, math

I've created the database for library management system.
The Query is to be return for the question below !!!

- Find fine payable(fine) against each student of particular department for past 6 months
- Assumption: Fine amount is 2/day(either in cent or INR) and  it'll double for the second day, likewise 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256.......

my code for the question is:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(s.id) AS IDs,
GROUP_CONCAT(DATEDIFF(returned,exp_date)) AS DAYS,
GROUP_CONCAT(POW(2,DATEDIFF(returned,exp_date))) AS FINE_PER_HEAD,
SUM(POW(2,DATEDIFF(returned,exp_date))) AS Fine,s.dept
FROM student s
INNER JOIN borrower b
ON s.id=b.id
WHERE returned>exp_date AND exp_date 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW() 
GROUP BY s.dept;`
```

In the output i got 2^33 cent (33 days)in the fine Column [Here,The Image contains the output screen of the result that i got from the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BRpy.png)

```
IDs               DAYS        FINE_PER_HEAD          Fine       dept
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1,36,138          2,5         4,32                   36         CS  
116,104,109,112   1,11,8,33   2,2048,256,8589934592  8589936898 Electronics 
196               13          8192                   8192       Maths   
1,73,174          10,14       1024,16384             17408      Mechanical  
1,48,150          6,5         64,32                  96         Physics
```

How can i limit the fine amount that should not exceed the particular amount like < 5000 or 6000 cent> whatever , what should i do?

Comment: Is this a homework question? You should be clear about that if it is. Also, post results of things you have tried in the body of the question, not in external image links.

Comment: @jdv please answer the question, yup its my homework question but im not a student , im started working in a Software company and its my prelearning works............

Comment: No one is going to do your homework for you. Few are going to follow that link. Explain as clearly as you can what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: Hint: use the MAX() function. I'm always happy to help unqualified people get jobs :)